# SQL compare two strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016-express

I would like to ask for help. I am using this piece of code for comparing string variable. It always return true and executre the code inside.
Example:  variable1='Andrew' .. first select should return 'A', second select 'a' .. the whole if should return False, but instead return true.

```
IF (SELECT SUBSTRING(@variable1,1,1)) = (SELECT LOWER(SUBSTRING(@variable1,1,1)))
    BEGIN
    ...
    END
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  In many databases, the default comparisons are case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your collation configuration is *in-case sensitive*, so try to apply collation as `CS` (case sensitive).

```
declare @variable1 nvarchar = 'A'
IF (SELECT SUBSTRING(@variable1,1,1)) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = (SELECT LOWER(SUBSTRING(@variable1,1,1)))
    BEGIN
     print 'ok'
    END
```